# Is there a way to downgrade Andrdoid System WebView?

Tags: android, webview

I have a bug happening in an emulator within a WebView in the app.
I want to install the same version Android System WebView APK on a real device to check if it is happening on real devices.

I DOwnloaded the APK from apk mirror but the installation is failing because I already have the app installed on the device and you can't uninstall it and the version I want to install in lower than the version already installed.

So is there a way to downgrade the Android System WebView?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On rooted devices you can perform these steps to downgrade Webview:

1. Uninstall update for Android Webview
2. download an older version from the given link, https://android-system-webview.en.uptodown.com/android/versions
3. `adb connect  IP-OF-device`
4. `adb remount`
5. `adb push android-system-webview.apk /system`
6. `adb shell pm install -r -d /system/android-system-webview.apk`

Comment: is it work on non rooted device